# How to point %sql query in Notebook to an object in R

Tags: sql, r, jupyter-notebook, databricks

Recently I am working on a POC in databricks, where I need to move my R script to the Notebook in Databricks.

for running any Sql expression I need to point to %sql interpreter and then write the query, which works fine.
[image]

However, is there any way I can save this query result to an object:

```
%sql
a <- SHOW databases
```

This is not working, following is the error:
[image]

Please let me know if anything like is possible or not,as of now I can run using library(DBI)
and then save it using dbGetQuery(....)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the spark.sql interface as you are working in a Databricks notebook. Below is code which will work inside a Python DB notebook for reference.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# execute and store query result in data frame, collect results to use
mytabs = spark.sql("show databases").select('databaseName').filter(col("databaseName")=="<insert your database here, for example>")
str(mytabs.collect()[0][0])
```

Comment: Thanks, make sense. Although this has been already applied, using SparklyR

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Ricardo's answer, the first line in a command cell is parsed for an optional directive (beginning with a percentage symbol).

If no directive is supplied, then the default language (scala, python, sql, r) of the notebook is assumed.  In your example, the default language of the notebook is Python.

When you supply %sql (it must be on the first parsed line), it assumes that everything in that command cell is a SQL command.

The command that you listed:

`%sql
a <- SHOW databases`

is actually mixing SQL with R.

If you want to return the result of a SQL query to an R variable, you would need to do something like the following:

`%r
library(SparkR)
a <- sql("SHOW DATABASES")`

You can find more such examples in the SparkR docs here:
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/sparkr/overview.html#from-a-spark-sql-query

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, using %r and loading sparklyR and DBI, I am able to do this using dbQuery. Also we can do using SparkR as well as explained by you. However, this was more of a client specific requirement. So they need this to be done in %sql.